# Context API loses data on switching router links

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-glitter-3mpwx

hi,
in the above codesandbox there are two router links design and build it each of those links contains a counter component with individual context `DesignContextProvider` for Design and `BuildContextProvider` for build

counter variable is both available in `BuildContext` and `DesignContext` so what happens is when I increment the counter from `BuildContext`and switch to design route `BuildContext` loses data, resets to 0 and vice versa for `DesignContext`, feels like Context are getting rerendered and initial state is applied

what I would like to achieve is to maintain data on both Context even after switching `HashRouter` Links

BuildContext:

```
import { createContext, Component } from "react";

export class BuildContextProvider extends Component {
    
    state = {
        counter: 0,
    };

    updateCounter = () => {
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1,
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <BuildContext.Provider
                value={{ ...this.state, updateCounter: this.updateCounter }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </BuildContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export const BuildContext = createContext();
```

DesignContext:

```
import { createContext, Component } from "react";

export class DesignContextProvider extends Component {
    
    state = {
        counter: 0,
    };

    updateCounter = () => {
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1,
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return(
            <DesignContext.Provider
                value={{ ...this.state, updateCounter: this.updateCounter }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </DesignContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export const DesignContext = createContext();
```

App.js

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/build">
          <BuildContextProvider>
            <Build></Build>
          </BuildContextProvider>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/design">
          <DesignContextProvider>
            <Design></Design>
          </DesignContextProvider>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

Build and Design Component:

```
const Build = () => {
    const { updateCounter, counter } = useContext(BuildContext);
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={updateCounter}>+</button>
            <span>{counter}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

const Design = () => {
    const { updateCounter, counter } = useContext(DesignContext);
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={updateCounter}>+</button>
            <span>{counter}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the provider outside the route so the statie in the provider wont reset

```
<DesignContextProvider>
    <BuildContextProvider>
        <Switch>

        <Route path="/build">
            <Build/>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/design">
            <Design/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BuildContextProvider>
  </DesignContextProvider>
```

Comment: But in that case, I would be fetching data for all the Providers when user only wants to visit Build page currently here there are only 2 router links but in my main project file there are 5 links so 5 seperate providers including reports provider which would have huge amount of data..

Comment: If you want to keep the state you will need to place the provider around the route components. 
You could have a function fetchData in the providers and use a useEffect in the Build and Design to call the fetchData.

Comment: David we can do that but the problem is ill be calling data for other 4 tabs when user only wants to visit one of them so ill be collecting data for other 4 tabs which i dont think its appropriate since ill be using codesplitting for all 5 tabs what im trying to achieve here is data to split with all other 4 tabs and when user only visits it once then the data should be loaded

Comment: Prem, Maybe this is a option for you. if you make one StateProvider around it all where you just keep the state and set the state. in the build and design you can have al the logic/functions. so then the StateProvider stays small and just has the state, and the other providers can get bigger but only loads when the page is loaded.

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-kowalevski-nsqnq?file=/src/Context/StateContextProvider.js